# Release memory in client while allocation done in DLL?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have created a regular dll where I have one method `GetRecord` to allocate memory for `RecordInfo` structure.

```
struct RecordInfo{
  // Some Data member
}

BOOL GetRecord(RecordInfo *& pRecordInfo)
{
   // Allocate RecordInfo, fill data and return as out paramter.
}
```

Now I access this dlls from MFC application and after finish my work. I release RecordInfo in client using delete.

```
delete pRecordInfo;
```

In release mode there is no problem, However in debug mode application shows assertion failure. Can some one explain reason behind this behaviour.

Comment: You seem to have heap corruption. One thing you can try is to enable the first chance exception in visual studio and see whether you can find the cause for the corruption.

Comment: Note that the debug build is actually _helping_ you with its diagnostics infrastructure and related assertion failure; instead the release build is silently failing. (In general, before moving to release builds, you should make sure that debug builds run fine.)

Comment: You can't allocate memory from one allocator and then release it to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allocate memory in a DLL and free it in client code, you should make sure that both the DLL and the client are built with the **same version of the compiler** and **same CRT** "flavor" (e.g. both are debug builds, or both are release builds).

This is of course highly constraining.

As an alternative, to decouple things better, you can export from the DLL functions to both *allocate* and *deallocate* your data structures (in your particular case you could add and export a `DeleteRecord` function from your DLL, and call `delete` from inside this function body).

I suggest you reading [this interesting blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/09/23/9898230.aspx) on the Old New Thing blog, and note especially the beginning sentence (emphasis mine):

> It should be second nature to you that the code which allocates
>   memory and the code which frees memory need to use the *same allocator*.

Answer (score 2):

Memory allocation and deallocation should be done on the same side of the component / dll.

A more elegant solution is to populate a `std::unique_ptr<RecordInfo>` instead.

Comment: The `unique_ptr` only wraps deletion, but the actual call is still made from the consumer (which has its own copy of the template).

Answer (score 1):

Producer and consumer need to agree on a common allocator. In the Windows world, the sanest choice is `CoTaskMemAlloc`/`CoTaskMemFree`, which was written precisely for this purpose.

Comment: Can be use CoTaskMemAlloc/CoTaskMemFree with regular dll, as this dll not using any MFC library.

Comment: Yes, these functions are really old and predate MFC. :)